# Encrypted Elementary doesn't boot on first try

Tags: release-loki, boot, encryption

After installing nvidia-370 drivers from official PPA, I cannot boot into my system from first try. So, basically each time I try to start my machine, after initial bios diagnostics it produces this:
[image]

Text is mine. What I meant to say - it should have allowed me to enter password, but it doesn't. No terminals are available either.

Then, after force shutdown and reboot, I get this:
[image]
On which I successfully can enter my password and boot up the system.

So my question is - how do I fix this? The best solution would be to enable decrypting elementary using standard text-box (on first screen), but if it's not possible, I agree for console option.

Comment: Can you give more context on your drive setup and how/when you set up the encryption?

Comment: I setup encryption during install (whole disk encryption I presume).

Drivers from here:
https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Nvidia 370.28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, that seems like a regular problem across Linux, when people try to use NVIDIA drivers and encrypted file-system. Plymouth doesn't play well with NVIDIA.

The temporary solution is to disable splash screen during boot:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

In editor, change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash quiet"`. Make the same adjustments to the`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` if it's not empty.

And then update grub using `sudo update-grub`.

Hope it helps somebody.

More info:

1. [Cannot enter password to start Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574296/cannot-enter-password-to-start-ubuntu)
2. [passphrase input-box for encrypted disk is not shown](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1530548)
3. [Password not accepted graphical boot for encrypted root system](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1386005)

Comment: Going to try this now seeing I have the same issue, I will edit this comment as needed after reboot.... nope, same issue, I will check that I saved the changes correctly though. Found it: the above changes are correct with one exception, the timeout is adjusted by nvidia to a value of 5, I reset this to 0 along with the changes listed above and am now error free.